# Getting compile time error while typecasting void * pointer variable to unsigned int to uint32

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I am trying to typecast a value of `void *` type to `uint32` but getting error after compile:

> error: cast from pointer to integer of different size

Comment: On a 64 bit system, `sizeof(void*)` probably equates to 64 bits; i.e. larger than a `uint32`.

Comment: yes but have to pass to a function taking argument of type uint32

Comment: If you've got two liters of stuff to put into a one liter bottle, you're going to have to either rethink your problem or throw half of it away.

Comment: @D.Prakash What would you do if the cast succeeded? The function would only be getting *half* the value, so it wouldn't be able to reconstruct the pointer anyway.

Comment: @D.Prakash Well, it does not make sense to pass a void pointer to a function expecting uint32. Maybe if you posted the relevant code, someone can figure out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @Angew yes and i chaned the argument type to uint64 now working fine.

Comment: @D.Prakash. Don't use `uint64`; that just kicks the can down the road. Use the type `uintptr_t` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the C standard says is this, C11 6.3.2.3/6:

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
>   the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
>   type.

This means that it is up to the compiler to specify what will happen on the given system. Apparently your particular compiler things that the result can't be represented and therefore throws a diagnostic message.

What you should do instead is to cast to `uintptr_t`. This type is guaranteed to be large enough to contain an object pointer value.